# Access specific html objects with jsdom?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I am trying to analyse a webpage to look for existing html forms in it - and access them as objects in js.

Right now I have successfully queried it with `node-html-parser`, and I create a`JSDOM` object like this:

```
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
const window = new JSDOM(form).window;
```

However I don't understand how to get/extract it as a specific html element:

```
const mySpecificHtmlElement = window.HTMLFormElement;
const prototype = mySpecificHtmlElement.prototype; // like so?
console.log(prototype.className); // <-- crash
```

It crashes with: `"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Illegal invocation at HTMLFormElement.get className [as className]"`. and with similar error when trying to: `console.log(prototype.method);` - even though the html in `form` both has method and class set.

How can I access the html as its specific type with jsdom?[image]

Comment: You are accessing the element constructor function/prototype not the element itself. You want to use methods like `getElementById`, `querySelector` etc if you want to get actual element objects

Comment: The form in this case does not have an id. Also, if it would have had an id I would get a `HTMLElement` - not `HTMLFormElement`. Can I cast it in js?

Comment: Unless you need form specific functions like `submit()`/`reset()`, which dont make sense trying to use server side, you wouldnt really need the exact class. HTMLElement should get you most of what you would need, css class manipulation, add/removing child elements etc. For instance you would be able to use `className` wither or not it is HTMLFormElement or HTMLElement

Comment: The background is that I am making a mobile app for a client that has a website. And I am thinking of grabbing the form action uri and get all available input types and values - as well as the full post uri with parameters - from the website. Right now I am simply testing with node. I think I will need the specific html objects but I am not sure yet.

Comment: You will need the element objects to get those values but you wont need those objects to be the specific instance, meaning for what you want the objects being given to you as HTMLElement will be fine